# Proving equality of two formulas in logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am trying to prove the following equality of two formulas:
$x,z$ are variables, $c$ is a constant and $t$ is a term.

$\alpha {t \over x}{z \over c} =\alpha {z \over c}{t' \over x} $,

with $t' = t {z \over c}$ and we also assume $z \notin var(\alpha,t)$.

$\alpha {z \over c}$ means we replace the constant c with the variable z and $\alpha {t \over x}$ means we replace the variable $x$ with the term $t$, whenever $x$ occurs free in the formula $\alpha$.

Intuitively, the equality is clear to me: if $c$ occurs in the term $t$, on the left side we then replace the term $t$ for x and afterwards we replace $z$ for the constant $c$, so that $c$ does not occur in the formula, anymore.
But if we go from the right side, we first replace $z$ for $c$ and because we have already replaced $z$ for $c$ we need to set $t' = t {z \over c}$, so that $c$ does not occur in the formula anymore.

But I have no idea how to formally prove this, since you cannot really work with the definition of the substitution (at least in my eyes...)

Comment: It looks like this _ought_ to be a simple induction on the structure of $\alpha$, applying the definitions of the various substitutions. This depends on exactly how the substitution is defined, of course. (I can even imagine that it might not be true if the substitution is being too clever about inserting capture-avoiding renamings for free -- but it looks like you have an explicit assumption to deal with that case).

Comment: The definition of the substitution is basically what I wrote above, so just replacing the symbols (at least that's what it says in W. Rautenbergs book about logic).

Comment: I tried a formula induction, starting to show the equality for prime formula, so when $\alpha$ is of the form $s_1 = s_2$ for terms $s_1, s_2$, but then I have the same problem that I don't know how to use the substitution definition...

Comment: Don't you have a symbolic definition with cases such as $[s_1=s_2]\frac tx \equiv s_1\frac tx = s_2\frac tx$? Without such a definition I have trouble imagining how a proof of _anything_ about substitution would look, other than a blob of vigorous handwaving.

Comment: Sorry, yes we have this definition, and I tried it, but I couldn't use that definition to show the equality..

Comment: The equality case would go something like $$ [s_1 = s_2]\frac tx \frac zc \equiv \Bigl[s_1\frac tx \frac zc = s_2\frac tx\frac zc\Bigr] \equiv \Bigl[s_1\frac zc\frac{t'}x = s_2\frac zc\frac{t'}x\Bigr] \equiv [s_1=s_2]\frac zc\frac{t'}x$$ where the middle $\equiv$ comes from the induction hypothesis.

Comment: what kind of induction do you mean ? My induction hypothesis is $z \notin var(\alpha, t)$

Comment: No, that is not an induction hypothesis. Doesn't your text contain an example of how structural induction works?

Comment: Our text contains a formula induction.. it goes like this: Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a property of a symbol sequence, such that 1) $\mathcal{E} \alpha$ for all prime formulas $\alpha$ (so $\alpha$ of the form ($s_1 = s_2$) and

Comment: x @Gilligans: One would then expect that there is a corresponding "term induction" principle that you could start by applying to show that $s\frac tx\frac zc \equiv s\frac zc\frac{t'}x$ for all $s$, as a first step.

Comment: 2) $\mathcal{E} \alpha, \mathcal{E} \beta \Rightarrow \mathcal{E} (\alpha \land \beta), \mathcal{E} (\alpha \vee \beta)$

Comment: Ahh wow, yes you are right.. now things are getting clear

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot :)